# Dynamically jQuery use .append() add inputs , but posting form is not append data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use appends add inputs , but post form is not add inputs data.

where wrong with my code?

HTML code

```
<form class="form_a" action="test_a.php" method="POST" >
<div class="language">
    <div class="append">

    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add">add Button</button>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
$('.language .add').click(function(){
    $('.language .append').append(
        '<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">'
    );
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST['language']);
?>
```

Comment: Typo: </buttond> should be </button>

Comment: but  post form is not append add inputs data.

Comment: $_POST does contain all the field values... Please post your complete PHP script.

Comment: sorry,  edit  this is ok?

Comment: So your php code above is your complete test_a.php file, is that it?

Comment: And you have jQuery referenced in your HTML page, right?

Comment: yes, this is my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

`</buttond>`

for

`</button>`

, the form works just fine. Wrapping your javascript in a jQuery call helps:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.language .add').click(function(){
        $('.language .append').append($('<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, where change? How can I do?

Comment: I can append input,  but  I submit  form  , php is  not  append data

Comment: I have it working here just fine. Please post your complete test_a.php page.